# Missing number, treated as zero. in eqnarray

Tags: equations

this is my code:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
[A,C]\mid_{dom(x)} = -x^1x^2\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1} + (2(x^1)^2 - (x^2)^2 +2)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}  \\
[B,C]\mid_{dom(x)} = ((x^1)^2 - 2) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1} -5x^1x^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2} 
\end{eqnarray}
```

and this the error:

```
54
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   B
l.54 [B,C]
          \mid_{dom(x)} = ((x^1)^2 - 2) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1} -5x^1x...
```

I would be glad if you help me, I cannot figure out the problem and solve it. I am a new Tex learner :/

I could not write the comment, anyway I like to thank you, these advices of yours solved my little problem!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It seems you're missing the `&`, before the `=` signs. In this case it's better to use `align` of the `amsmath` package than `eqnarray`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/18228

Comment: Since it hasn't been explained, the reason for the error is that `\\ ` of `eqnarray` has an optional argument which is expected to be a length. So your first `\\ ` takes `[B,C]` for its argument, and finds no length there, producing the error. The `amsmath` `align` environment is better in many ways, and this is just one of the minor ones.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `eqnarray`. Use `align*` from amsmath.

Further, `dom(x)` looks like an operater, hence you may put `\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}` in the preamble and use it as `\dom(x)`. I have also used `\bigl` and `bigr` from amsmath to make `[` and `]` bigger.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}
\begin{document}
 \begin{align*}
[A,C]\mid_{\dom(x)} &= -x^1x^2\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1} + \bigl[2(x^1)^2 - (x^2)^2 +2\bigr]\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}  \\
[B,C]\mid_{\dom(x)} &= \bigl[(x^1)^2 - 2\bigr] \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1} -5x^1x^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]